# salto de linea en una lista

Tags: tkinter

Tengo un proyecto de python donde recopilamos datos en una lista, pero estos se imprimen de manera horizontal y no vertical ¿Alguien sabe cómo imprimir una lista verticalemente?

pd: es dentro de una ventana mediante tkinter

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. A que te refieres con "imprimir". No existe el concepto de "imprimir" dentro de tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

haber perdon si entendi mal tu pregunta .Lo que entendi fue que cogieras una lista y la imprimieras de manera vertical,y no horizontal.En ese caso lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *

def lista_vertical(lista):
   listaF=""
   for i in lista:
      listaF+=i+"\n"#no recuerdo bien si era /n \n pero bueno se entiende
   return listaF


ventana=Tk()
a=["palabra1","palabra2","palabra3"]
b=lista_vertical(a)  
label=Label(ventana,text=b)
label.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

asi se ve en una ventana tkinter el resultado
[image: Tkinter]

¿te fue útil mi informacion?
valorala por favor :)

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo añade el `\n` después del texto que quieras añadir el salto de línea. Por ejemplo.

```
variable = "hola \n como estas?"
```

Ya con eso en la ventana de salida te saldría el salto de linea.